# Convert Instance Fields into Properties

Tags: python, properties, python-decorators, readonly-attribute

I would like to convert all instance fields of an object into properties (getter only) in order to make them read only. The fields might be defined by a subclass.

How can I achieve this?

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):

        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

        convert_all_instance_fields_into_properties(self)   # implementation ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve readonly fields using python builtins quite easily:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.foo = val

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if not hasattr(self, key):  # only for first set
            super(X, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            raise ValueError


def main():
    x = X('bar')
    y = X('baz')

    assert x.foo == 'bar'
    assert y.foo == 'baz'

    # raises ValueError
    x.foo = 'Raise an error!'
```

If you want to specify which fields are readonly

```
class X:

    readonly = ['foo']

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.foo = val

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.readonly and not hasattr(self, key):
            super(X, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not such things as "private" in Python. If you want to and try hard enough, you can extract anything.

There are 2 levels of semi-private:

- one underscore prefix for internal use, normally accessible outside - but most IDEs will underline it and warn about a not recommended practice
- two underscore prefix for pseudo-private, still accessible if someone really wants it but ugly

Most of the time, you only want one underscore - people will access it only when they think they really need it.

In the code I'm working with, I saw two underscores used only as a way of encapsulating lazily loaded properties (one underscore was a "getter" and checked whether variable is already loaded).

Remember, that even with a "getter" you will be returning an object unless you return a copy yourself. Rethink your design, think in Python, rather than in "private" and "getters". ;)

---

Edit:

Seems like I misunderstood the question.

Functions marked with `@property` decorator will return without parentheses to call them (`spam.eggs`, instead of `spam.eggs()`) and be "read-only" (you can do `bacon = spam.eggs` but not `spam.eggs = bacon`).

**BUT the rest of my comment still stands:**

- everything is accessible if one is determined enough
- use underscores to ask people nicely not to access the value
- if your getter property returns a mutable object, it will still be changeable inside (only reference will stay the same), e.g. `eggs.list = []` will not work, but `eggs.list.append("spam")` will!

Comment: You are confounding _private_ and _read-only_ here. I want it to be public but read-only. I.e. `a = obj.foo` works, but `obj.foo = 2` not.

Comment: Edited my answer to address the read-only part. It's too early for me.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of all the issues you have pointed out. But this is not an answer. An answer would be: _this is how you do it_ or _it's not possible_. 
If you think it's bad style, fair enough, put it in a comment. Please make it a real answer, or I'll have to flag it.

Comment: I explained *how* you can do something *similar* to what you want. And that **there will be always a way to access and change your "read-only" variable**. And in my edit I explained how `@property` decorator works (with examples what will work and what won't). What else do you want? You can't "convert" something like in your question, you have to write the code pythonically and use what I gave you.

Comment: You can convert it in the sense that you can remove the field (I know that that is possible), and add a property (possible too).
For what I want, is that people give me an answer to my question, and not an answer to some other question (whether it is pythonic or not).
And to be able to have a civil discussion, please, thanks.

Comment: "And to be able to have a civil discussion" - it was you who threatened me with report. <eyeroll> I wanted to delete my answer but it was too late, and I am at work ("it's too early for me" above meant I was answering it before work and it seems my brain doesn't work without coffee), so I only quickly edited it. You know that with my answer you can write everything yourself, right? I explained everything there is to know. But it seems you want a copy-paste code fragment.